# WEBrick rails server won't start

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, webrick

**Could you please recommend a fix?**

*Remedies I have tried based on other SE questions:*

- run bundle install
- run gem cleanup
- run bundle exec rails server
- run sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
- remove root password (to match database.yml config file)

*Installed:*

- OSX 10.8.3
- Ruby 2.0.0p0
- Rails 3.2.13
- mysql2 gem 0.3.11
- 'mysql2' in Gemfile
- Mysql 14.14 5.6.11

*To Reproduce:*

- Starting Location: ~/Sites/simple_cms
- Run "rails server"

I then get the following output:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Unknown database 'simple_cms_development' (Mysql2::Error)
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/Sites/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/rh1n0cer0s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

*Here is my gem list:*

```
actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.2)
i18n (0.6.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.2)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0, 3.12.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
sass (3.2.8)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.3.7)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.0.1)
```

*Contents of my database.yml*

```
   development:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: simple_cms_development
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password:
      socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

    test:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: simple_cms_test
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password:
      socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

    production:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: simple_cms_production
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password:
      socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Is your mysql correctly configured in your OSX? Can you access it with  `mysql -uroot` in your terminal?

Comment: thanks @kiddorails - I think so...I set it up w/password and can log in using terminal.  Could it have something to do with the password not appearing in the database.yml config?

Comment: If you have password on `root` account, then you _must_ specify in database.yml :)

Comment: Did you run **rake db:create**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run `rake db:create` to create your database? After that, `rails server` should work.

Comment: Hi Nathan - I created the database and linked it to my ruby project (simple_cms)...there's already a database.yml (see above).  I'll try your suggestion but before I do is there a reason rake will work instead?  Do I need to run it at a certain level of the directory structure?

Comment: Nathan and @Sparda thanks...server is running using rake db:create...I installed mysql and created the database without doing this step and thought it was already created

Comment: Hey, any chance you could please mark this answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in the terminal and then starting your WEBRick server.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Edit: Got the solution from here, seems like it might be the same situation you're in.

Comment: Thanks @JoshEmory - Do you know what this does or why it works?  sudo can also do harm if not used correctly.

Comment: @djmb Yes sudo commands can do harm. But this particular command can't actually do any harm to your computer. Basically the libmysqlclient.18.dylib file seems to be installed in a different location than where it's being looked at (on a lot of these computers). This command is creating a symbolic link where rails is looking for it. A symbolic link is just a small pointer file, so if someone looks at it in the place with the symbolic link, they'll actually see the file from the other location. Think of it like a copy, but instead of actually copying, it's just pointing.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response Josh

Comment: As he said, it just creates a symbolic link for that sql lib, and it will be fine. :)

Comment: Thanks Josh and kiddorails - I'm still not able to get the server to run (see new output above)