# WEBrick rails server is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

My operating system is Windows 10

Today I have installed Ruby (ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]) and rails gem (rails 4.2.4)

I am following a proceedure set out in a series of tutorial videos about rails.
I have the following version of myqsl 2 installed (and reinstalled in case it was a dirty install) mysql2-0.4.1-x64-mingw32

This question pertains to a application called simple_cms created in the following fashion as per instructions on the tutorials

```
rails new simple_cms -d mysql
```

I have:

- run bundle install a few times
- used gem cleanup
- run bundle exec rails server
- tried to rake db:create and bundle exec rake:db create each method as suggested[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283936/webrick-rails-server-wont-start)
- reinstalled mysql2 a few times

However upon input of

```
rails server
```

in the root of my project simple_cms. WEBrick fails to even kick off

By way of example in other similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283936/webrick-rails-server-wont-start) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992302/trouble-starting-rails-server-webrick), both of the inquirers receive the following

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

etc ..etc....before the failure of WEBrick. However I do not eve get this far as there is no mention of anything to do with WEBrick. Below is the error message I receive after typing the rails server command:

```
simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-     4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:7:in `<class:Template>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:6:in `<module:WebConsole>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Lizanne/Documents/Code/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What can be done to rectify this situation as i am now going round in circle trying the same thing over and over again , and as Einstein rightly stated the definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results.

i have the following gems installed

```
actionmailer (4.2.4) 
actionpack (4.2.4)
actionview (4.2.4)
activejob (4.2.4)
activemodel (4.2.4)
activerecord (4.2.4)
activesupport (4.2.4)
arel (6.0.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6)
byebug (6.0.2)
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0)
globalid (0.3.6)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
jbuilder (2.3.2)
jquery-rails (4.0.5)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.2)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
mysql2 (0.4.1 x64-mingw32)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2 x64-mingw32)
power_assert (0.2.5)
psych (2.0.15, 2.0.8)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.4)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.4)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
sass (3.4.19)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
sdoc (0.4.1)
sprockets (3.4.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2015.7)
uglifier (2.7.2)
web-console (2.2.1)
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you make a new project in a new directory and start up the server, do you get this error still? (`rails new test_project; bundle install; rake db:create; rails s`)

Comment: check approved [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766656/nameerror-on-executing-rails-s)

Comment: Kalelc that worked, You are a diamond. !!!!!!!!!! (jumps for joy)

Comment: kalelc put it in the answer sections rather than the comment so i can rate it as correct. May i ask what is the problem causes by the newer version of rails and WEBrick in this instance....or is the answer massively complicated ?

Comment: @Aerosewall1 ready :)

Comment: Apologies klalec, since I'm new here I cant rate you answer, until I get 15 points at which point I will return here and give you the thumbs up

Answer (score 2):

Check approved [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766656/nameerror-on-executing-rails-s)

It is a problem between versions `railties` and `rails` gems. Yeah, is a answer complicated. For future developments try to use some versioning system for your projects ([Rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv))